# packages missing

Tags: networking, package-management

I installed ubuntu 20.04.1 on my new computer.
First problem: i don't have internet, i download my network driver from my second computer, i put it on a usb stick, i try to install the driver like they say in README but im missing a package, i try to install the package needed like i did for my network package (with usb stick) but im missing another package and it repeat like that for a lot of packages.

My question, is there a way to update my ubuntu (like apt-get update something like that) in my ubuntu without internet connection (and network driver), or install a packages of packages( something like that) that install every package i need to run ubuntu.

Im missing packages like : gcc gcc-9 gcc-8 etc. libc6 libc6-dev-bin make (and a lot more)

Sorry if its hard to read english is not my main language.

Comment: Have you internet during Installation or live-session?

Comment: i have internet on my windows boot but no internet on ubuntu boot

Comment: If the answer is a solution to your problem, you should mark the answer as the solution by clicking the ckeckmark icon to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your phone using a USB cable and enable USB modem feature.

This will let you install everything.